# Shift date based on the time

Tags: r, datatable, dplyr

I am trying to shift the date by each ID based on the time limit. For example, I need to add a separate column as Date Modified which will take entries as same day until 5AM of next day. And entries post that will be considered as next day.

```
 ID     Date and Time   Date         Time   Date Modified
13462   9/4/2019 15:38  9/4/2019    15:38   9/4/2019
13462   9/4/2019 20:23  9/4/2019    20:23   9/4/2019
13462   9/4/2019 23:23  9/4/2019    23:23   9/4/2019
13462   9/5/2019 4:23   9/5/2019    4:23    9/4/2019
13462   9/5/2019 7:23   9/5/2019    7:23    9/5/2019
```

When I try to add the date + 1 based on the time it is coming as number. Hoping for some suggestions.

```
df1%>%
  group_by(ID)%>%
  mutate(Date_Modified = ifelse(format(Date and Time,"%H:%M:%S")>="05:00:00",as.Date(Date)+1,as.Date(Date)))
```

Comment: use `if_else` instead of `ifelse`

Comment: @MauritsEvers: `ifelse` converts time to numeric, while `if_else` doesn't, and I think it address OPs question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `lubridate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
 mutate(Date = mdy(Date),
        mod_Date = if_else(hour(hm(Time)) < 5, Date - 1, Date))

#     ID Date_and_Time       Date  Time Date_Modified   mod_Date
#1 13462 9/4/201915:38 2019-09-04 15:38      9/4/2019 2019-09-04
#2 13462 9/4/201920:23 2019-09-04 20:23      9/4/2019 2019-09-04
#3 13462 9/4/201923:23 2019-09-04 23:23      9/4/2019 2019-09-04
#4 13462  9/5/20194:23 2019-09-05  4:23      9/4/2019 2019-09-04
#5 13462  9/5/20197:23 2019-09-05  7:23      9/5/2019 2019-09-05
```

Also I don't think you need `group_by` `ID` here since no calculation is done by group here.

---

Using base R,

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
inds <- as.integer(format(as.POSIXct(df$Time, format = "%H:%M"), "%H")) < 5
df$Mod_date <- df$Date
df$Mod_date[inds] <- df$Date[inds] - 1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(13462L, 13462L, 13462L, 13462L, 13462L), 
Date_and_Time = structure(1:5, .Label = c("9/4/201915:38", 
"9/4/201920:23", "9/4/201923:23", "9/5/20194:23", "9/5/20197:23"
), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("9/4/2019", "9/5/2019"), class = "factor"), 
Time = structure(1:5, .Label = c("15:38", "20:23", "23:23", 
"4:23", "7:23"), class = "factor"), Date_Modified = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("9/4/2019", "9/5/2019"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: I am not facing any issues with the base R method. However, with dplyr I am getting error in parse_hms. Hence getting converted into NA's

Comment: @ssan are you using the same data as shown? Actually, base R and `dplyr` are doing the same thing so I am not sure what could be causing that error. Also I am not using `parse_hms` function. Try this on a fresh session and if you still face the error can you post `dput` of your data ? `dput(head(df))`

Comment: Looks like converting time format is creating error. In my data, the time field is in Character" format. could that be a reason?

Comment: Should not be. Can you try the code for the data which I have shared ? Does that work ? What output do you get with `hm(df$Time)` on your data ?

Comment: It is working fine with the data you have shared. I think the possible reason could be the my data format. When I change the format in your data I am getting the same error.

Comment: @ssan What format of data do you have ? Can you share it with `dput` in the same way as I have done ?

Comment: I am not able share the data due to restrictions and I am accepting this answer as I am able to do that by base R. Thanks fro your support